# include header file from a new folder "cannot open include file - no such file or directory"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, header-files

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 for a simple console app but i am having trouble including a header file which i want to make as a config file

**directory looks like this**

```
-AI
  --config
    --config.h
  --Header Files
  --Resource Files
  --Source Files
```

**AI.cpp**

```
// AI.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdio>

//include config file
#include "../config/config.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace std;

config c;

int main()
{

    count << "My name is: " << c.getName;
    std::getchar();

}
```

**config.h file**

```
Class config
{

    public void getName(){
        return 'Awesome'
    }

}
```

When i click the Build button i get the following error:

```
1>AI.cpp(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config\config.h': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Right click on the include and click on Open Document "config.h". If VS can't resolve the path you'll get an error that tells you where it looked.

Comment: That's what the Solution Explorer window looks like.  Not what the file system looks like.  Items like "Header Files" are not directories, they are "filters".  Good odds that "config" is not actually a directory either.

Comment: thanks, i actually didn't have to specify any folder path... just the file name "config.h" and it worked.... other than the other errors on the functions but it seem to solve this problem for now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution from **VoidStar**:

```
Right click on the include and click on Open Document "config.h".
If VS can't resolve the path you'll get an error that tells you where it looked.
```

Comment: I just had this problem. Accidentally unchecked `inherit from project defaults` in properties